# Putting html hover on right while adding text on right

Tags: html, css

I tried floating the the code from left and right and also aligining it from left and right but it doesn't stay on the same line like either text or the hovering image is above the other. I'm kinda confused on what i'm doing wrong, can you guys possibly help me?

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/W3Pxv/344/

```
<span class="right"><a href="http://discord.me/animalcrossingchat"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/1HcjGUB.png?1" onmouseover="this.src='http://i.imgur.com/Y3qUfNt.png?1'" onmouseout="this.src='http://i.imgur.com/1HcjGUB.png?1'" /></a></span><span class="left">Animal Crossing Community gives you an unlimited amount of possibilities. Do you want to share some unforgettable moments of your own animal crossing experience or just talk about anything noteworthy that comes to your mind on our plaza? Why don't you grab a cup of coffee and talk about more serious matters in the roost? Become a premium member and enjoy a variety of new features and much more.

Be part of our community by earning bells, answering the question of the day or winning valuable prices on our server's contests. You are what you make yourself to be on Animal Crossing Community. Join today and become the newest member.</span>
```

Css:

```
.right {
    float:right;
}

.left {
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: put in the right jfiddle, my bad.

Comment: It is hard to understand what you are trying to accomplish. Do you want to get the image on one side and text in another as opposed to one below the other the way it is now?

Comment: Please format your code properly - it is hard to read

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give `.left` a display of inline-block and a fixed width.

Like so:

```
.left{
    width: 420px; // size is interchangable
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/W3Pxv/348/

Comment: @AntonioVallez please mark as fixed your problem if it helped you :)